# What is going on Under the hood in C# Compilation?

Tags: c#, console-application

**Simple and Very Intersting Problem:**

From the below Code, I was wondering that In both conditions the `Check` variable will be `true` but i was wrong.

```
using System;
namespace Problem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int firstNumber = 1;
            int secondNumber = 9;

            bool Check = false;

            Console.WriteLine("Checking First Condition.");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------");
            if (firstNumber == (firstNumber = secondNumber))
            {
                Check = true;
                Console.WriteLine("First Check : {0}", Check);
            }
            else
            {
                Check = false;
                Console.WriteLine("First Check : {0}", Check);
            }

             Console.WriteLine("------------------");
             Console.WriteLine();
             Console.WriteLine("Checking Second Condition.");
             Console.WriteLine("------------------");

            // Resetting firstNumber value:
            firstNumber = 1;

            if ((firstNumber = secondNumber) == firstNumber)
            {
                Check = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Second Check : {0}", Check);
            }
            else
            {
                Check = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Second Check : {0}", Check);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

But from while ago and thinking about it.
but i can't get it why the first condition returning `True`

**Dry Runs:**

First Condition.
`(1 == (1 = 9) // firstnumber = 9. so 9 == 9 // True.`

Second Condition.
`((1 = 9) == 1) // firstnumber = 9. so 9 == 9 // True.`

Output:

[image]

Can someone explain breifly what is happening under the hood ?

// What is done by a  C# Compiler in  both the cases ?.

Comment: The 1st number is getting changed before you do any testing : firstNumber = secondNumber

Comment: Two words:  [Operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=vs-2017).

Comment: I'm not sure why the first condition is returning true, because when I run the code, it returns false: https://i.imgur.com/brF47or.png . Side note, assignment will return the value assigned.

Comment: In general, you should avoid trying to be fancy and using constructs like `if ((firstNumber = secondNumber) == firstNumber)`.  Yes, the operator precedence rules are well documented and consistent, but you shouldn't make your reader stop and think too hard about what your code is doing.  Clarity is a great way to avoid bugs, and to make maintenance programmers' lives easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

conditions/expressions are evaluated from left to right. so,

```
 int firstNumber = 1;
 int secondNumber = 3;
```

**First Case:**

```
firstNumber == (firstNumber = secondNumber)
     1      == (firstNumber = secondNumber)
     1      == (     1      = secondNumber)
     1      == (     1      =      3      )
     1      ==   3
          false
```

**Second Case:**

```
((firstNumber = secondNumber) == firstNumber)

 (     1      = secondNumber) == firstNumber
 (     1      =      3      ) == firstNumber   
 (            3             ) == firstNumber   //firstNumber became 3
              3               ==     3 
                             true
```